# Modelling the speed control of a mobile robotic system

Tags: dc-motor, control, transfer-function, pid-controller, mobile-robot

I am attempting to model a robot and develop a PID based off of the paper at the bottom of this post before developing a physical model. However, the research paper appears to give parameters for wheel radius, a geared motor inertia and a tachometer constant but these are not included in the overall transfer function stated in the paper - unless these would be factored in by the parameters for equivalent damping / inertia?

Were I to include these parameters so to achieve a more realistic model how would that be done? The transfer function relates the speed of the robot to the voltage applied across the DC motor - so I presume this multiplied by the wheel radius can give the velocity of the wheels.

Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Edit: Section of paper below

[image: System]

Comment: Do you think, that we all have a subscription to IEEE?

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: Please quote relevant section(s) of the linked paper for users who don't have access to it.

Comment: Edited so to include a drive link of the paper vs. IEEE link - thank you

Comment: Um, are you now publishing a copyright IEEE paper?

Comment: Posted the actual system instead of paper, see attached

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. The transfer function (although very blurry) has J - inertia, B-damping, and you say that are not included. Now where to include them? You proposed only the transfer function, so that's the only place to include, since there is nothing else in your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
This is the block diagram of DC motor, similar you should have in your article:

And this is the transfer function of it:

$$ \dfrac{\Omega(s)}{u_q(s)} =\dfrac{{k_\Phi}}{s^2L_qJ + s{R_qJ+L_qF}+{R_qF+k_\Phi^2}}
$$

Replacing the upper \$k_{\Phi}\$ in the diagram with \$k_T\$ and the lower one with \$k_v\$ we get almost the same transfer function as your blurry one, except B=F, :

$$ \dfrac{\Omega(s)}{u_q(s)} =\dfrac{{k_T}}{s^2L_qJ + s{R_qJ+L_qF}+{R_qF+k_v\cdot k_T}}
$$

You have to place the inertia and friction parameter in the feedforward path of your position controller \$T=J \alpha + F \Omega\$. The approx. amount of torque is known "a priori" with these two parameters known.

Where to place Radius-R(not resistance)? \$l=\Theta R\$;  \$\Theta =\dfrac{\Omega}{s}\$